# (Visual Studio)Calculation _using for sentence

Tags: c, visual-studio, for-loop, average, calculation

Want to elicit average of entered real value,until negative value is entered.
My problem is

1. My calculation don't quit when negative value is entered
2. It keep asks printf sentence for 3 time.
   What did I do wrong?

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int main(void)
   {
    double total = 0.0;
    double input=0.0;
    int num = 0;

    for (; input >= 0.0;)
    {
        total += input;
        printf("real number(minus to quit):");
        scanf_s("%1f", &input);
        num++;
    }
    printf("average:%f \n", total / (num - 1));
    return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: You explicitly ask `scanf` to read only one character. `-1` (for example) is *two* characters.

Comment: You also *must* check what `scanf` (or `scanf_s` in your case) [***returns***](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: You can try getting a string as input, break if it is equal to "-" and otherwise use a function like `atoi` to convert the string.

Comment: @user3121023 You're correct, it's probably a typo of the OP when reading the code from a book or other source that couldn't be copy-pasted.

Comment: @yjr can you confirm out suspicions that it's a typo when you wrote the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have many problems with your code :

1. it's not `%1f` in the line `scanf_s("%1f", &total);` as `%1f` will give you undefined behavior , it's `%lf`as you are scanning a double , there is a big difference between number **one** and **lower case L**
2. the function called `scanf` returns an integer indicating how many elements could be assigned to the input that the user entered , so , you should do `if(scanf_s("%lf", &input) == 1)` to check if the assignment done successfully, that will help you in detecting if `-` is entered instead of the number
3. if the user entered a lonely `-` then `sacnf` will fail to convert and you have to take another approach
4. when you are printing the average in this line : `printf("average:%f \n", total / (num - 1));` , you actually prints a double , so it's `%lf` instead of `%f`
5. the condition of the for loop is incorrect , you are saying `for (; input >= 0.0;)` but this will prevent you from entering any negative values as when entering a negative value , the for loop will break , so you could use `while(1)` instead of the for loop and only break when a `-` is entered alone

---

so here is my edited version of yours , I introduced a dummy string to read the buffer and check whether the input was a lonely `-` or not , and if not then I try to convert it to double and here is my edited solution :

```c
      #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    int main(void)
    {
        char dummy[30];
        double total = 0.0;
        int num = 0;
        double DecimalConverted = 0;
    
        while(1)
        {
    
            printf("real number(minus to quit):");
            fgets(dummy, 30, stdin);    // gets the input into the buffer
    
            if(dummy[0] == '-' && dummy[1] == '\n') // break from the loop on condition that '-' only entered
                break;
    
            // convert the string to decimal
            DecimalConverted = strtod(dummy ,NULL);
            if(DecimalConverted == 0)
                printf("not a number\n");
            else{
                total += DecimalConverted;
                num++;
            }
    
        }
        printf("average:%lf \n", total / (num - 1));
        return 0;
    }
```

and here is the output :

```
real number(minus to quit):12
real number(minus to quit):-51
real number(minus to quit):-
average:-39.000000
```